# maven not found on Mac OSX Catalina (10.15.4)

Tags: maven, maven-3, macos-catalina

I am trying to install maven on Mac OSX catalina (10.15.4), I have moved the apache maven folder  (apache-maven-3.6.3) to Applications folder.

```
% pwd
/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
```

In `.bash_profile`, I made the below entry

```
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

I have restarted the system but when I am trying to find maven version it says `mvn` not found.

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % mvn -version
zsh: command not found: mvn
```

Below is my echo path

```
 % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Did you use homebrew to install maven ? Does $PATH really contains the changes you made ? please check by echoing the $PATH in terminal

Comment: No, I have installed homebrew on my system. But I did not use homebrew to install maven. I have updated my question with echo path result on my system

Comment: You are using `zsh` - move your settings to: `~/.zshrc`; `.bash_profile` is for `bash`. If you type in `man zsh` and go to the very end of the help, you will be able to find all the files that are used by `zsh`.

Comment: I have noticed the file /etc/zshrc,  do you want me to move the contents of my .bash_profile to /etc/zshrc file?

Answer (score 0):

maven on Mac OSX catalina
.bash_profile doesn't work in OSX cataline any more, it changes from Bash to Z shell : ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zsh or ~/.zshrc.

Simple fix: from the root directory: to find root use pwd

```
touch .zshrc        
open .zshrc .
```

Add your desire maven path, open a new terminal / may reboot system this should help you to resolve the issue you are facing.

```
root user directory  ~ % mvn -version                              
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (............)                    
Maven home: /..........         
Java version: 1.8.0_261, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /.....        
Default locale: ...                             
OS name: "mac os x", version:......
```